# Rails 3 Counting Records by Date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to build an array that looks like this via a model method:

`[['3/25/13', 2], ['3/26/13', 1], ['3/27/13', 2]]`

Where, the dates are strings and the numbers after them are the `count` of an table/object.

I have the following model method right now:

```
def self.weekly_count_array
  counts = count(group: "date(#{table_name}.created_at)", conditions: { created_at: 1.month.ago.to_date..Date.today }, order: "date(#{table_name}.created_at) DESC")
  (1.week.ago.to_date).upto(Date.today) do |x|
    counts[x.to_s] ||= 0
  end
  counts.sort
end
```

However, it doesn't return the count accurately (all values are zero). There seem to be some similar questions on SO that I've checked out, but can't seem to get them to work either.

Can someone help (1) let me know if this is the best way to do it, and (2) provide some guidance in terms of what the problem might be with the above code, if so? Thanks!

Comment: what  exactly you are getting in `counts` variable in that method? Is that query returning the values as you are expecting?

Comment: I'm trying to total the number of records from that specific day. And no, the `counts` seems to be the part breaking.

Comment: Sorry, misread the question. The method above returns the proper array in terms of formatting, but has 0's for all the object counts, even though objects exist for some days.

Comment: The specific count within that method returns empty `=> {}` even though an object exists with today's date.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use this as a template if you wish

```
def self.period_count_array(from = (Date.today-1.month).beginning_of_day,to = Date.today.end_of_day)
  where(created_at: from..to).group('date(created_at)').count
end
```

This will return you a hash with dates as key and the count as value. (Rails 3.2.x)

Comment: That was the problem with my code above- I was pushing out the `Date.today` without specifying `end_of_day`. As a result, the object wasn't showing for today. So, the code in my question works, it was just a matter of adding that, but this is a more elegant solution for a hash for sure. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

maybe this is what you are trying to do?

```
class YourActiveRecordModel < ActiveRecord::Base

  def.self weekly_count_array
    records = self.select("COUNT(id) AS record_count, DATE(created_at) AS created")
      .group("DATE(created_at)")
      .where("created_at >= ?", 1.month.ago.to_date) 
      .where("created_at <= ?", Date.current)

    records.each do |x|
      puts x.record_count
      puts x.created # 2013-03-14

      # use I18n.localize(x.created, format: :your_format) 
      # where :your_format is defined in config/locales/en.yml (or other .yml)
    end        
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Fantastic answer by @Aditya Sanghi.

If you have the exact requirement, you can opt:

```
def self.weekly_count_array
  records = select('DATE(created_at) created_at, count(id) as id').group('created_at')
  1.week.ago.to_date.upto(Date.today).map do |d| 
    [d, records.where('DATE(created_at) = ?', d.to_date).first.try(:id) || 0]
  end 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a process to perform the count. Simply perform a query for this.

```
def self.weekly_count_array
    select("created_at, COUNT(created_at) AS count")
    where(created_at: 1.month.ago.to_date..Date.today)
    group("created_at")
    order("created_at DESC")
end
```

Comment: I want to put the count into an array though, with the date being the other component. Without the process, there are no zeros.

Comment: Ok You can create an array with all dates and counters zeros and just do a merge with the dates and counters returned by the query.

Comment: You're going to have to show me an example of what you mean. The method you posted above simply puts the object into an array without listing all the dates. I'm look to have an array like the one in the original question returned from the method, with the date and count for each day, and zero for days that have no count.

Answer (score 0):

Built on @kiddorails Answer,

so not to make a lot of Requests to the DataBase, Created a Hash from the ActiveRecord

& changed the group from .group('created_at') to .group('DATE(created_at)') to base it on date

```
def self.weekly_count_array
   # records = select('DATE(created_at) created_at, count(id) as id').group('created_at')
   records_hash = Hash[Download.select('DATE(created_at) created_at, count(id) as id').group('DATE(created_at)').map{|d|[d.created_at, d.id] }]
   1.month.ago.to_date.upto(Date.today).map do |d| 
     [ d, records_hash[d.to_date] || 0 ]
   end 
end
```